# replace a line from a rich text box in c#

Tags: c#, replace, richtextbox, line

So I'm attempting to replace a line in a rich text box in visual studio 2010. For a project I'm making a menu system and when an item is selected I need to update the text box which shows the number of that item. I wont know the specific location where the item is in the list, and there could be multiple items that display the same number so i can't use the .replace method. I can get the line number that the item is on, but when i try to use the index that i used to find the line number i get an error saying "StartIndex cannot be less than zero." Here's the code i have so far:

//keep track of the number of each item

```
    int[] mainItems = new int[10];

    //function for menu item buttons
    private void MenuButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        string s = btn.Name.ToString();
        //if item doesnt already exist on order
        if (!textBoxItems.Text.Contains(s))
        {
            textBoxItems.Text += "\r\n• " + s;
            //track num of each item
            switch (s)
            {
                case "Tiramisu": mainItems[0]++;
                    break;
                case "Lazania": mainItems[1]++;
                    break;

            }
            textBoxCount.Text += "\r\n(1)";
        }
        else
        {
            int itemID = 0;
            switch (s)
            {
                case "Tiramisu": mainItems[0]++;
                    itemID = 0;
                    break;
                case "Lazania": mainItems[1]++;
                    itemID = 1;
                    break;

            }

           int lastIndex = 0;
            //get line number of item
            do
            {
                index = textBoxItems.Find(s, index + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    lastIndex = index;
                }
            } while ((index != -1));
            //int lineNum = textBoxItems.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
            //MessageBox.Show("" + lineNum);

            textBoxCount.Text.Remove(lastIndex, 2);
            textBoxCount.Text.Insert(lastIndex, "(" + mainItems[itemID] + ")");

        }
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you loop until index == -1

```
while ((index != -1));
```

then immediately use that index

```
int lineNum = textBoxItems.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
```

I'm not sure exactly what the logic of the while loop is, but at first glance, you may want to break out if index == -1. Or keep track of the last non-negative index outside the loop.

**Update**

To find the item the user just clicked on, you need to change the loop to record the last index that is not -1. The purpose of the while loop is to find the last occurrence of s, but you have to record the last valid occurrence in a separate variable (lastIndex in the code below). You also must test that something was actually found after the loop completes.

Here is how I would implement this logic:

```
        int lastIndex = -1;

        //get line number of item
        do
        {
            index = textBoxItems.Find(s, index + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
            if (index != -1) {
               lastIndex = index;
            }
        } while ((index != -1));
        if (lastIndex !+ -1) {
            int lineNum = textBoxItems.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);
            //messageBox.Show(""+lineNum);
            textBoxCount.Text.Remove(lastIndex, 3);
            textBoxCount.Text.Insert(lastIndex, "(" + mainItems[itemID] + ")");
        }
```

Comment: thats the code i got off the msdn page. the line number was just for testing and it seemed to work for that because it did give the line num for that item. what would i change the while loop to if i wanted the index of the item the user clicked on?

Comment: @Donovan: I updated the answer to explain what the loop is doing, why it is broken, and how to fix it.

Comment: hopefully i shouldn't have to make sure something was found because if it wasn't there it was added in. i think i understand what your doing and when i tried it it gave the error "Index and count must refer to a location within the string." i tried changing the number of characters removed and it still gave the same error. i'll update my post with the new code..

Comment: @Donovan: Sorry, I just realized that index was also being using in the remove and insert methods; I updated the answer to change them to use lastIndex, which should solve your issue.

Comment: ya i tried changing them and that's when it gave the error i mentioned earlier. somehow the index its coming up with isn't in the string

Comment: I see your issue: you are finding the string in textBoxItems, but using lastIndex to update textBoxCount.

Comment: oh waiti know what the problem is its that the number of the item and the items themselves are two seperate text boxes. i just need the index thats on the same line as the one in the items box